# std::List item not being removed

Tags: c++, stl, std

I am having some issues with list items not being removed from std::list. For some reason the item stays in the list and the list did not decrement. In other words, the list container could not find the element.

Here is my List:

```
std::list<IPressable*> interactables;
```

and this is the code that is deleting the item:

```
void RemoveInteractableobject(IPressable* object)
{
    interactables.remove(object);


    //This did not work either
    //interactables.erase(std::remove(interactables.begin(), interactables.end(), object), interactables.end());
}
```

IPressable is an abstract class inherited by intractable objects.

I have made sure that the pointer address exists in the list.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening? I am not the most experienced person in C++, but this is an interesting problem!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The use of `std::list::remove` is correct, so the issue is probably elsewhere in the code; for example you might be copying the list inadvertently.

Comment: Provide a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org)! What's a *pointer address*?

Comment: Heve you tried debugging your code and see the values of `object` and `interactables` before and after that line?

Comment: @buc the value of both remain the same. The pointer is still list in the items of the list and the `object` pointer remains the same (address and values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oswald was correct; the issue was somewhere else in my code. The issue was that IPressable is an abstract class that is being used in a multiple inheritance. Because of this, I could not compare pointers or even values. My code executing this was:

```
void DestroyRemovalStackedOBJS()
{
    while (!removalStack.empty())
    {
        TreeNode* currentNode = removalStack.top();

        RemoveChildFromOtherObject(currentNode, currentNode->parent);

        RemoveInteractableobject(dynamic_cast<IPressable*>(currentNode));

        removalStack.pop();

        delete currentNode;
    }
}
```

the code above removes the nodes out of a tree structure (parenting hierarchy) and a list (used to manage all objects explicitly).

The problem was that I did not have a `dynamic_cast<IPressable*>`. This typecast converted it to the proper type and thus the address + data was properly aligned to the type (this is somewhat of a guess)

If someone knows the proper explanation to what is going on, please let me know!

Answer (score -1):

To erase from the list you need to have iterator reference, you might want to try that.  First loop over your list to get the iterator reference for the object you are looking for and pass it on to erase of your list, it should work. More info http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html

Comment: The use of `std::list::remove` is correct. The issue is elsewhere in the code.